# Prove $(X,C^\infty_X)$ is a locally ringed space

Tags: abstract-algebra, differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry

Let $X\subset \Bbb{R}^n$ be open subset of $\Bbb{R}^n$, equiped with the structure sheaf $C^\infty_X$, I want to prove $(X,C^\infty_X)$ is locally ringed space, I have understand the stalk is local ring, with the maximal ideal the germ of function vanish at that point.

Given smooth map $\varphi:X\to Y$ with the induced map $$\varphi^\flat(V):C^\infty_Y(V)\to \varphi_*C^\infty_X(V) \\f\mapsto f\circ \varphi \tag{*}$$ via adjunction it will induce a map $$\varphi^\sharp:\varphi^{-1}C^\infty_Y \to C^\infty_X$$

---

To prove it's local homomorphism on the stalk, we need to consider the map on the stalk$$ \varphi^\sharp_x : C^\infty_{Y,\varphi(x)} \to C^\infty_{X,x}$$

The problem is I don't know how to work out the expression on the stalk explicitly, if should be the pull back map, however I have no idea how to deduce it from (*)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pull-back map $\varphi ^\flat$ is $f\mapsto f \circ \varphi$, isn't it?
Let us remind that any element of the stalk is represented as an image of $C^\infty_Y(U) \to C^\infty_{Y,\varphi (x)}$ for some $\varphi(x)\in U\subset Y$, and representatives of the elements in the maximal ideal satisfy $f(\varphi(x))=0$. Let us take an element of $f_{\varphi(x)}\in C^\infty_{Y,\varphi(x)}$ in the maximal ideal and its representative $f\in C^\infty_Y(U)$.
Then we have the commutative diagram:
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
C^\infty_Y(U) @>{\varphi^\flat }>> \varphi_* C^\infty_X(U) \\
@VVV @| \\
\varphi^{-1}C^\infty_Y(\varphi^{-1}(U)) @>{\varphi^\sharp}>> C^\infty_X(\varphi^{-1}(U)) \\
@VVV @VVV \\
C^\infty_{Y,\varphi(x)} @>{\varphi^\sharp_x}>> C^\infty_{X,x}.
\end{CD}
The upper square is commutative by the following argumant:
First, we have the inductive system $C^\infty_Y(V)$ where $V$ moves $\varphi(\varphi^{-1}(U))\subset V $ open, and $U$ is one such. The family of morphisms on it $\varphi^\flat(V): C^\infty_Y(V)\to C^\infty_X(\varphi^{-1}(V))\to C^\infty_X(\varphi^{-1}(U))$ are compatible with restriction morphisms on $V$ since $\varphi^\flat$ is a morphism of presheaves. So, they factorizes through $$\varphi^+(\varphi^{-1}(U)): \varphi^+C^\infty_Y(\varphi^{-1}(U)) =\varinjlim_{\varphi(\varphi^{-1}(U))\subset V}C^\infty_Y(V)\to C^\infty_X(\varphi^{-1}(U)),$$
where $\varphi^+$ denotes the associated presheaf and morphism of prsheaves in terms of $\varinjlim$. And again $\varphi^+$ factorizes through $\varphi^\sharp: \varphi^{-1}C^\infty_Y \to C^\infty_X$, its sheafification morphism, by definition. Decomposing $\varphi^\flat(U)$ twice and composing once we obtain the upper square.

Thus, $\varphi^\sharp_x(f_{\varphi(x)})$ is represented by $\varphi^\flat(f)=f\circ\varphi\in \varphi_*C^\infty_X(U)$, whose value at $x $ is $f(\varphi(x))=0$, showing that its image in $C^\infty_{X,x}$ belongs to the maximal ideal.

Comment: Hi  @Acrobatic , why the upper diagram is commute? I have worked out the diagram but do not know why it commute.

Comment: I was thinking if we can do it without involving the sheafification(use the adjointness result directly) for example we know $\varphi^{-1}$ and $\varphi_*$ are adjoint, therefore it will have a morphism of functor $\epsilon: \text{id} \to \varphi_*\varphi^{-1}$ then apply the identy functor $\text{id}$ to the morphism in the first row of the diagram?

Comment: @yili I'm sorry but I'm not so familiar with categories.  I recommend Hilton-Stammbach's *A Course in Homological Algebra* for the treatment of adjoint functors.